# How do I change the background here to use a moving image .mp4 file vs a .webp file?

Tags: html, jsp

How do I change the background here to use a moving image .mp4 file vs a .webp file?

Our landing page at https://profitsharingprojects.com uses this source file https://github.com/tpoffice1/one_off_files/edit/main/uc.jsp

How do I use a reference to an mp4 file here instead of a reference to a webp file?

```
<body style="background-image:url('/res/img/site_background.webp')">
```

Comment: Can you describe in your question what happens when you use an mp4, and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply by:

```
 <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
 <source src="(Your source file)rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Comment: OP seems to want a CSS solution, not an HTML one